# How to search and group in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch index with records like:

```
{
  "project" : "A",
  "updated" : <date>,
  "cost"    : 123
},
{
  "project" : "A",
  "updated" : <date>,
  "cost"    : 1
},
{
  "project" : "B",
  "updated" : <date>,
  "cost"    : 3
},
{
  "project" : "B",
  "updated" : <date>,
  "cost"    : 4
},
{
  "project" : "C",
  "updated" : <date>,
  "cost"    : 5
}
```

I'm trying to draw "cost" chart by selected projects.
Can anyone help me to build a query to get a sum of cost, grouped data by a project?
F.e. I want to select data for projects "A" & "B" and get something like:

```
date1 ->
  projectA -> sum(cost)
  projectB -> sum(cost)
date2 ->
  projectA -> sum(cost)
  projectB -> sum(cost)
```

Have no idea how to modify this query, which extracts data for the one project:

```
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "project": {
                "query": <project>,
                "type": "phrase"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "updated": {
                "gte": <startDate>,
                "format": "epoch_millis"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "3": {
        "date_histogram": {
          "field": "End_Time",
          "interval": "1M",
          "time_zone": "CST6CDT",
          "min_doc_count": 1
        },
        "aggs": {
          "2": {
            "sum": {
              "field": "cost"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

> *Upd:* Thanks guys! With your help I wrote the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "End_Time": {
              "gte": 1485892800000,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Project_Name": {
              "query": "A",
              "type": "phrase"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Project_Name": {
              "query": "B",
              "type": "phrase"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "End_Time",
        "interval": "1M",
        "time_zone": "CST6CDT",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "project_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Project_ID"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "2": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "Cost"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it returns something strange:

```
"aggregations": {
 "3": {
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key_as_string": "2017-02-01T00:00:00.000-06:00",
      "key": 1485928800000,
      "doc_count": 17095,
      "project_agg": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 36,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 3503,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "2": {
              "value": 2536.8616891294323
            },
            "key": 834879987748,
            "doc_count": 2243
          },
          {
            "2": {
              "value": 3438.766646153458
            },
            "key": 497952557271,
            "doc_count": 1785
          },
          {
            "2": {
              "value": 13066.367076588496
            },
            "key": 1057394416300,
            "doc_count": 1736
          },
          ...
```

Here are 10 buckets for each month. I expect to see only 2 values for each project. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate on project before you aggregate cost:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "End_Time",
        "interval": "1M",
        "time_zone": "CST6CDT",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "project"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "cost"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the filtering it depends on how you want to do the search. For a list of projects you could use:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "terms": { "project": [ "a", "b" ] } } //Assuming field is mapped as "analyzed"
      ]
    }
  }
```

In case your mapping contains a .keyword variety, you would format the terms filter like this:
{ "terms": { "project.keyword": [ "A", "B" ] } } //Assuming field is mapped as "not_analyzed" or has a keyword field.
Here is an example of how a field is mapped in ES 5.5 as "text" with a "keword" field:

```
  "ShortTextContent" : {
    "type" : "text",
    "fields" : {
      "keyword" : {
        "type" : "keyword",
        "ignore_above" : 256
      }
    }
  }
```

In this case I can access the analyzed version using "ShortTextContent" and the not_analyzed version using "ShortTextContent.keyword"

Comment: Thank you! But when I'm trying to use "terms" I get empty results. But values are exactly the same. Do you have an idea why? Looks like "should"+"match" keywords are working. I'm using 5.0 version.

Comment: Can you add the mapping for the objects you're trying to report on? If the terms query are giving zero results it could be due to fields being mapped as "analyzed" (meaning it will typically lower-case the text). For instance, if you index the project names "A" and "B" using analyzed mapping, it may store them as "a" and "b", and you would have to use the lowercase variant for a terms query. In later elastic versions you can access a "fieldname.keyword" field for a not_analyzed version, i.e. "project.keyword". you could also specify this in the mapping before indexing your data.

Comment: Thank you! I've replace "Project" to "Project.raw" and not it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The query you wrote gives you total cost(irrespective of project) per month, you need to have another aggregation to group by project in between `aggregation 3` and `aggregation 2`.

If you only want for projects `A` and `B`, then use filter in aggregation.

```
"size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "project": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "project": [
                           "a",
                           "b"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "3": {
               "date_histogram": {
                  "field": "End_Time",
                  "interval": "1M",
                  "time_zone": "CST6CDT",
                  "min_doc_count": 1
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "project_agg": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "project"
                     },
                     "aggs": {
                        "2": {
                           "sum": {
                              "field": "cost"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but I getting strange results. Do you have an idea why? (I've updated the post)

Comment: I've updated the aggs query to filter only projects "a" and "b", which should do.

Comment: I found out. My problem in "Project" field it was not "aggregatable", but "analyzed". So, agg didn't throw any errors but returns something weird. I replaced "Project" to "Project.raw" and not it's working fine. Thank you for help!